# cant access oulook email or app store without password pop up

Tags: store, microsoft-account, outlook

Pop up screen keeps asking for password. When I enter password it still comes back to the same screen. Can't access app store read my email or anything. It just started doing this outta the blue. Did not do this as long as I had the damn phone

Comment: Are you able to press back button and bypass the screen?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the pop up screen? Is it asking for your Microsoft Account password or something else? Are you sure you're typing in the correct password? What OS version is your phone running?

Comment: Sounds like the password is being rejected - are you able to log in to https://account.microsoft.com/ from the phone (or failing that, from a PC)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to go through without password, you must be facing trouble in signing in your microsoft account. What you have done is perhaps you have tried to sign out from all of the devices using your PC or another signed in device (other than this one). What you should do is:

- Make sure you are connected to network.
- Go to Settings>Accounts>Email & Accounts> Add Account.
- Here select Microsoft account.
- Add your account.
- If your account is already there then remove and add your account again.
- If doesn't work please change your password and try the procedure again.
- Also soft reset the phone after signing in.