# Phone asks for Microsoft Account Password on app downloads

Tags: store, microsoft-account

I have 15 apps to download but it just will not update anything. It keeps on asking for my Microsoft account password . i never had a password on my phone?

I have rebooted my phone but still no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/14051/106

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is asking for your Microsoft account password and not your phone password. You should have a Microsoft (Outlook) account before you can use the Windows Store Service and download or update apps.

You can make a Microsoft Account [here](https://signup.live.com/signup?lcid=1033&wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1483683047&rver=6.7.6640.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.live.com%2Fowa%2F%3Fnlp%3D1%26signup%3D1&id=292841&CBCXT=out&fl=wld&cobrandid=90015&uaid=ed30b32df2514e6aabd6912a6530705a&lic=1). Follow the on-screen directions to complete the procedure.

Next, you'll need to sign in to the account on your phone. Go to Settings > email+accounts > Microsoft account. Enter your email and password, then try to update the apps.

Give me an upvote if it helped. If you still have some problems, ask me in the comments.